# The query can't be executed!ERROR: 22P02: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""1"

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

I am trying to import csv to postgres through c# code the query is i am guess right but i get error :

> The query can't be executed!ERROR: 22P02: invalid input syntax for
>   type numeric: ""1"

My code to do this is:

```
string identification_client = "COPY identification_des_documents_complementaires_export (cle_ref,TRANSPORTEUR, Mode_transport, Code_Pays_ISO_3, Ref_Doc, Nb_Exp) FROM 'E:/MDE/KMP/App_Data/CSV/test_alpha/identification_des_documents_complementaires_export.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' ";
```

where the csv file contains this http://prntscr.com/9p22rp
and the DB has following columns http://prntscr.com/9p22vp

How to fix such that I won't have this error again.

Comment: If you look at the file in raw CSV are there any double quotes wrapped around the first column? Although you screenshot shows column 1 as 1, in raw csv this could be different. I'd check by opening the file with notepad or notepad++.

Comment: Yes i saw in notepad++ and removed the "" and it wrked